# what is the Difference between the camelContext and routeContext in Apache Camel

Tags: spring, apache-camel

What is the difference between the camelContext and routeContext in Apache Camel? When to use camelContext and routeContext?

Answer (score 6):

As per Camel Documentation :

It is now possible to define routes outside `<camelContext/>` which you do in a new `<routeContext/>` tag.
The routes defined in `<routeContext/>` can be reused by multiple `<camelContext/>`. However its only the definition which is reused. At runtime each CamelContext will create its own instance of the route based on the definition.

http://camel.apache.org/configuring-camel.html